# chrome development tools - JavaScript code is not complete in Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was doing some modifications in javascript on some website in Google Chrome to see what changes appear on the web page.

What I observed that I am not able to see the complete javascript code on the element tab in developer tools. The same code exists on the Source tab able to modify that but those modification doesn't work at it doesn't work once DOM is loaded. This is the screenshot of what I am getting:

> It is in HTML edit mode and this script is part of html page.... at
>   the end, it is not a complete script.

**ScreenShot:**
[image: in Edit mode]

**Is there any way to get it complete in element tab or any other way to modify script?**

Comment: I think you can get full script in the Edit Html feature

Comment: this in the only question. I am not able to get the full script. any useful comments will be helpful rather than just pointing the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the  tag and select "Edit as HTML", you'll be able to access the whole script, without the hyphenation.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to change Javascript code through the source tab and expect it to run your new code on reload. If you want to run Javascript on a website with Google Chrome Developer Tools, I'd suggest using the console tab and adding the code you'd want to run on the website. It won't save, but it's essentially the same as injecting Javascript to run on a website.

Comment: but the code which is exposed is editable. what about that or you are trying to say that if I will change that it won't make any effect..?